# Tensorflow, how to restore vars from array?

Tags: tensorflow

I use an example have variables like

```
weights = {
    # 5x5 conv, 1 input, 32 outputs
    'wc1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5, 5, 1, 32])),
    # 5x5 conv, 32 inputs, 64 outputs
    'wc2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5, 5, 32, 64])),
    # fully connected, 7*7*64 inputs, 1024 outputs
    'wd1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([7*7*64, 1024])),
    # 1024 inputs, 10 outputs (class prediction)
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1024, n_classes]))
}

biases = {
    'bc1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([32])),
    'bc2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([64])),
    'bd1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1024])),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]))
}
```

so that I can't use code below to restore vars

```
wc1 = tf.get_variables("weights[wc1]")
```

Then how can I restore variables use tensorflow?

Answer (score 1):

You have a reference to the variable simply by

```
weights["wc1"]
```

the command `tf.get_variable` is used in another way, if you want to use it to recover a variable already created,  you need to be in a variable scope with `reuse = True`, and use the name that tensorflow has associated to the variable, not the python pointer. For instance:

```
with tf.variable_scope('var_scope'):
    v = tf.Variable(5, shape=(), dtype=tf.float32, name='my_var')

with tf.variable_scope('var_scope', reuse=True):
    v_again = tf.get_variable(name='my_var', dtype=tf.float32)
```

now `v` and `v_again` are two python variables pointing to the same tensorflow variable.